# Wikipedia API not returning image for certain titles

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I am doing a project for college and using the wikipedia API to pull in images,
however some requests are failing to return results,
For example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&titles=Racing_Point_F1_Team
The query returns data exactly as it should.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&titles=Mercedes-Benz_in_Formula_One
This request fails to return an image.

I have tried converting to UTF, or URLencodinng already, althought the above were created by just copying from the URL of the actual wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve the second image link because no image fit the rules of the extension in charge of selecting the best possible image to illustrate the article.
Extension in question is [Pageimages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages), which provides the [query action](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages) of the same name. The extension selects the image that will be returned by the query with this rule:

> The best possible page image on Wikimedia wikis is one of the first
> four images in an article which has a width/height between 400-600px
> and a height/width which is twice the value of the other dimension.

The logo of the team in page `Mercedes-Benz in Formula One` is too small, and the following 3 images haven't the proper height/width ratio. Thus, the extension haven't created any database entry for the page.